# Mapper Class not found error while executing Hadoop Program using SpringData

Tags: hadoop, spring-data

I am trying to run mapreduce using SpringData.
I have created a Mapper class,Reducer class,Main class & application context.xml.

Application context consists of Hadoop configurations.
Hadoop is setup in a linux based ubuntu machine.
Program is executed from a windows environment.

In Hadoop,in Coresite.xml,for authentication I have given a username through which the program will be executed.

My Configuration file is as follows:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

        <context:property-placeholder location="resources/hadoop.properties" />

        <hdp:configuration>
        fs.default.name=${fs.default.name}
        mapred.job.tracker=${mapred.job.tracker}
        </hdp:configuration>


        <bean id="jobConf" class="org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf">
            <constructor-arg ref="hadoopConfiguration"></constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <value type="java.lang.Class">com.hadoop.basics.WordCounter</value>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>

        <hdp:job id="wcJob" configuration-ref="jobConf"  
        mapper="com.hadoop.basics.WordMapper"
            reducer="com.hadoop.basics.WordReducer" input-path="${wordcount.input.path}"
            output-path="${wordcount.output.path}" user="hduser">
        </hdp:job>



        <hdp:job-runner id="wcJobRunner" job-ref="wcJob" run-at-startup="true" />


    </beans>



    and My main class is


    package com.hadoop.basics;

    import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    public class Main {

         public static void main(String[] arguments) {

             AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml", com.hadoop.basics.Main.class);

         System.out.println("Job running");
         }
    }


    and my Mapper and reducer classes are as follows


    package com.hadoop.basics;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;


    public class WordMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        private Text word = new Text();

        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer lineTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (lineTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String cleaned = removeNonLettersOrNumbers(lineTokenizer.nextToken());
                word.set(cleaned);
                context.write(word, new IntWritable(1));
            }
        }


        private String removeNonLettersOrNumbers(String original) {
            return original.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]", "");
        }
    }



    package com.hadoop.basics;

    import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

    import java.io.IOException;


    public class WordReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        protected static final String TARGET_WORD = "Watson";

        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            if (containsTargetWord(key)) {
                int wordCount = 0;
                for (IntWritable value: values) {
                    wordCount += value.get();
                }
                context.write(key, new IntWritable(wordCount));
            }
        }

        private boolean containsTargetWord(Text key) {
            return key.toString().equals(TARGET_WORD);
        }
    }



    and i am getting the following exception


    INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3b67a7: defining beans [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0,hadoopConfiguration,jobConf,wcJob,wcJobRunner]; root of factory hierarchy
    Oct 31, 2013 5:03:15 PM org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.JobExecutor$2 run
    INFO: Starting job [wcJob]
    Oct 31, 2013 5:03:15 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient copyAndConfigureFiles
    WARNING: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
    Oct 31, 2013 5:03:15 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat listStatus
    INFO: Total input paths to process : 1
    Oct 31, 2013 5:03:15 PM org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader <clinit>
    WARNING: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    Oct 31, 2013 5:03:15 PM org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy <clinit>
    WARNING: Snappy native library not loaded
    Oct 31, 2013 5:03:15 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient monitorAndPrintJob
    INFO: Running job: job_201310301940_0007
    Oct 31, 2013 5:03:17 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient monitorAndPrintJob
    INFO:  map 0% reduce 0%
    Oct 31, 2013 5:03:38 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient monitorAndPrintJob
    INFO: Task Id : attempt_201310301940_0007_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hadoop.basics.WordMapper
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:857)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:718)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hadoop.basics.WordMapper
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:810)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:855)
        ... 8 more
```

Please Help me out..

Comment: add in xml to hdp:job property: jar-by-class="com.hadoop.basics.Main"